# is it possible merge same select query in WHERE(MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

My case :
  TABLE AAAA : other table; 
      (include column1 : user1_seq, column2 :user2_seq,...)
  TABLE BBBB : user table;

1. I received only email_info in POST BODY DATA
2. I want to select All data `(user1_seq == email_info || user2_seq == 
   email_info)`

current my query :

```
SELECT * FROM AAAA
    WHERE
        user1_seq = (SELECT seq FROM BBBB WHERE user_email = 'test@mail.com')
    OR
        user2_seq = (SELECT seq FROM BBBB WHERE user_email = 'test@mail.com')`
```

BUT select query duplicated !! .. how can this solve it???

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please show us some data which illustrates your problem.

Comment: Your title says "MySQL" but you have tagged the question with `sql-server` those are two very different database products. Which one **are** you using?

Comment: i used MYSQL ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (`Inner Join`)-

```
select AAAA.*
from AAAA
inner join BBBB on (AAAA.user1_seq = BBBB.seq OR AAAA.user2_seq = BBBB.seq)
where BBBB.user_email = 'test@mail.com'
```

Above syntax is for `MS SQL SERVER`.
Check whether you need `Inner` OR `left join`.

Comment: it is exactly what i 'm saying ! Thank you for answer quickly!